# Retrofit upload is storing form data inside the upload file, corrupting it

Tags: android, azure, retrofit2, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I am using Retrofit 2 to upload an audio file to an Azure blob storage service via Azure's REST APIs.

The upload appears to work, but the file stored in the Azure blob container is corrupt because as well as the audio data it contains what appears to be HTTP headers. For example, these are the contents of one uploaded file:

```
--3c88cdb1-5946-432d-a129-cc8e930d014c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tape"; 
filename="/data/user/0/blahblah.mp4"
Content-Type: audio/mp4
Content-Length: 8365

...expected binary data blah blah blah ....
--3c88cdb1-5946-432d-a129-cc8e930d014c--
```

What am I doing wrong?

My upload function looks like this:

```
    val tapeFile = File(fileName)
    val tapePart = tapeFile.asRequestBody("audio/mp4".toMediaType())
    val tapeBodyPart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("tape",tapeFile.absolutePath, tapePart)
    tapeAzureWebService.uploadTape(url, tapeBodyPart).enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) { 
    etc etc
```

My Retrofit interface interface is like this:

```
@Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadTape(@Url url: String,
               @Part tape: MultipartBody.Part): Call<ResponseBody>
```

(It's using @URL because I'm using Azure SAS, with dynamic URLs with authentication embedded in the URL as a series of query strings, and that works very well and is a neat hint for anyone who stumbles on this, by the way, since it prevents Retrofit from encoding the URL and query.)

And my OKHttp Client looks like this, adding some headers that Azure demands:

```
class TapeAzureWebServiceAPI {

  fun service() : TapeAzureWebService {

    val headerInterceptor = object: Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val original = chain.request()
            val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                    .header("x-ms-version", "2015-12-11")
                    .header("x-ms-blob-type","BlockBlob")
            val request = requestBuilder.build()
            return chain.proceed(request)
        }
    }

    val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor(object : HttpLoggingInterceptor.Logger {
        override fun log(message: String) {
            logI("retrofit: $message")
        }
    }).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

    val client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
        this.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor)
        this.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
    }.build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(AZURE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .build()
    return retrofit.create(TapeAzureWebService::class.java)
  }
}
```

If I use a simple RequestBody rather than a multipart form, I still get the same corruption to the audio file, though there are fewer headers in the audio file.

I've looked at this a long time, and I can't tell if it's something I'm doing wrong in Retrofit, whether Azure wants different headers, or whether Azure simply doesn't like multipart form data.

thanks

John

Comment: `whether Azure simply doesn't like multipart form data` - That's the one. Whatever you upload, Azure Storage will save as is.

Comment: Is there a way to upload via Retrofit, or must I use some other library/technique? Thanks for your speedy reply, by the way!

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with Retrofit so I can answer that. However what you need to do is upload raw byte stream in Azure Storage without converting that to Multipart Form Data.

Comment: Thanks. That  points me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe just try with `RequestBody`? Essentially just use `tapePart` from `val tapePart = tapeFile.asRequestBody("audio/mp4".toMediaType())`?

Comment: That still creates the same problem, only with slightly different headers.

Answer (score 1):

remove `@Multipart` just add,

```
@Headers(  "x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob", "x-ms-blob-content-type: image/png")
@PUT
suspend fun uploadDocument(@Url url: String, @Body request: RequestBody)
```

and pass request body as,

```
val mediaType = "image/png".toMediaTypeOrNull()
val body = yourImageFile.asRequestBody(mediaType)
```